# Change specific letters in string using string manipulation

Tags: python

I want to create from this string using string manipulation:

string='Hello World'

this:

'heLLO wORLD'

and I tried a few manipulation and I didn't succeed

Thanks for the solvers...
:)

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, and explain why it didn't work

Comment: Why those letters? What are the conditions?

Comment: `'Hello World'.swapcase()`

Comment: this wouldn't give the expected result, isn't it? the snd letter in 'Hello' should be a small one after changing, swapcase would swap this too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I do not exactly the rules you want to realize. Here is a simple example, how you could do things. Tell us more about your rules and your tries and you will get better answers.

```
import random
def random_change_case(old):
    new = ''
    for c in old:
        r = random.random()
        if r < 0.4:
            new += c.lower()
        elif r > 0.6:
            new += c.upper()
        else:
            new += c
    return new

for i in range(10):
    print i, random_change_upper('Hello World')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have inbuilt `string.swapcase()` function for this. if you want to try some logical solution. check below

```
    string='Hello World'

    finalstr='' 

    for index, c in enumerate(string):
           if c.isupper():
              c=c.lower()
           else:
              c=c.upper()
           print(c)
           finalstr+=c
```